# Compile code with java8 and run with java17

Tags: java

I want to compile project using jdk8 and run it using jdk17. And my project use libraries which have been deleted in modern jdk (jdk.xml.bind, jdk.xml.ws).

My question is - will I get errors related to removed dependencies from modern jdk - jdk.xml.bind, jdk.xml.ws? Or if project was compiled using jdk8 which contains these packages inside, it would work fine with jdk17 in runtime?

Maybe I need to add these dependencies explicitly (rg.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime, com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri)?

Comment: When your code needs these classes, you have to add them.

Comment: @Holger got it, thanks for answering me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it really depends on how you compiled your code.

For instance, you can use a build tool, such as Maven for instance, and just include these dependencies in the project with the compile `scope`, which is the default one. And then if you are using some kind of a plugin that does fat jar creation: [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), for instance, or [spring-boot maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) plugin etc, then your project will have these dependencies at Runtime so you are good to go.

Of course you may not have these dependencies in the project or even more so you simply do not an access to the source code. So another option is to include them separately in the [JVM classpath during execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). This approach is similar (but not the same) to one people have when they deploy their Java application into an Enterprise web server such as WebSphere or JBoss.

Usually, the web server has required implementations and Java classes that are not present during compilation and they are just provided to JVM via classpath.

Comment: Thank you @vashdivan, if I helped you solve the problem, please accept the answer and upvote it :)